# Windows XP shut down window very slow to appear

Tags: windows-xp, performance, shutdown

I click Start->Shut Down and the Shut Down window takes 5 minutes to appear. This problem doesn't happen after a fresh boot, it only happens after I have been logged on for awhile. I am using a Macbook Pro with Boot Camp. The machine actually shuts down quickly, its just really slow to bring up the shut down window. Basically I would like to know if:

1) Anyone has any ideas why this would happen
2) Who owns the "Shut Down" window (I.e. what happens on the OS after I click the Shut Down icon in the start menu)

I've tried perusing the task manager to try and see if any processes look suspicious, but to no avail.

Comment: As a work-around, you could avoid the wait by pressing "u" after clicking shutdown, as windows should buffer the keystroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check your event viewer for any errors. see if any particular application is causing the slow shutdown.

Here are a few registry tweaks to speed matters up:

**Auto End Task**

This registry setting ends the running task and automatically shutdown the application

Go to Start > Run, type **regedit** to open Registry Editor.

Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Scroll down to find the registry key called **AutoEndTasks**. Right-click on the key, select Modify and change the value to 1.

Exit Windows Registry after making changes.

**Wait To Kill Application**

This registry key function is to set the time interval for Windows before killing the applications to shutdown the computer.

Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Scroll down to look  for the Registry Key called **WaitToKillAppTimeout**, right-click on it, select Modify and Change the value to 1000.

**Hang Application Time**

This registry key sets the hang time of the application before closing.

Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Scroll down to look for the Registry Key named **HangAppTimeout**.

Right-click on it, select Modify and Change the value to 1000, exit Windows Registry

**Clear Page File Before Shutdown**

Last but not least, make sure Windows doesn't clear the pagefile on shutdown:

Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`

Scroll down for the Registry Key named **ClearPageFileOnShutdown**, if this is set to 1, right click on it, select Modify and Change the value to 0.

**Wait To Kill Service Timeout**

This registry key sets the time for Windows to wait before ending services related to Microsoft.

Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`

Look for the Registry Key named as WaitToKillServiceTimeout, right click on it, select Modify and Change the value to 1000.

*[Source](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-speed-up-windows-shutdown-process/)*

p.s.: if you're looking for the easy way out, grab **[Superfast Shutdown](http://www.xp-smoker.com/freeware.html)**, it does what it says on the tin, guaranteed :)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I've had a bit more luck tracking this down - basically if I shut down the Windows "automatic updates" service it solves my problem. Why, however, the service starts to malfunction or cause the slowdown is another matter altogether...

Comment: Are these fixes for slow shutdown after clicking Ok in the "shut down  Windows" dialog box, or for the delay before delaying that dialog box after clicking the shutdown buton in the start menu? The latter is what the question was about.

Comment: None of these fixes are for the shutdown DIALOG taking a long time to show up, these are all for fixing the actual shutdown PROCESS, after the dialog has appeared and you have chosen to actually shut the computer down.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this issue three times at the shop I work at.  Of which one computer had several programs at startup that were malfunctioning and had to be removed, follow this [cleanup guide](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/expert/northrup_restoreperf.mspx) for help with that.

The other two pc's had several missing system files and damaged registry entries, a [repair load](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/helpandsupport/learnmore/tips/doug92.mspx) was required to correct the damage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by Nvidia driver service if you used some Nvidia device.

checkout my blog http://faund.sixserve.com/post/1/159

Comment: That link is a 404 :(

Answer (score 0):

I simply ran the error checking (My Computer >> C: >>  right-click on the icon,  Go to properties, click "Check volume for errors", tick the two boxes, let it run on startup.) It could take half an hour.  This cured my slow shut down problem.